# Audio Class A amplifier

Tags: amplifier, class-a

[image]Currently I am trying to copy the class A amplifier using the following components:
1k ohms Resistor, 10k ohms resistor, 470 ohms, 50k ohms Resistor, 2n3904 bjt transistor, 10 uF capacitor. With a speaker of 0.5 watts and 8 ohms.

However, there's no sound that it makes for the speaker. I just copy the class A audio amplifier.

Comment: Can you add a schematic of the circuit to your question please.

Comment: Thats my schematic diagram, dont bother to those unconnected wires.

Comment: @BrianPerez That schematic is a voltage amplifier stage, not a power stage. It's only one quadrant, not the required two quadrants needed to drive a speaker. And it is a highly distorting one, at that. What do you hope to use to drive this? Cellphone? Or? (There is a reasonable 3-BJT design that drive a speaker with a volume control, too.)

Comment: Drive by cellphone

Comment: You need an output coupling capacitor in sereis with speeker to remove DC component. 100uF should be ok.

Comment: I already added coupling capacitor but still the speaker did not sound.

Comment: If I add the speaker directly just to check if it is functionable, the speaker have sound. But when it is properly connected with transistor, the sound did not hear/appear

Comment: Change 470 to 100ohm to get higher gain. Also 10k to 4k7.

Comment: @BrianPerez Consider something more along [these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flxtU.png). It's also class-A and will work (to a degree.) It's a bootstrapped design so that one of the resistors, \$R_3\$ in the diagram, works more as a current source. It's also 2-quadrant so it is designed to deliver power. What you have won't do that. Look for a 9 V design that follows that template if a minimum number of BJTs is your goal.

Comment: @BrianPerez Another useful class-A design follows [this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz0Cs.png). It uses 4 BJTs.

Comment: When you show a schematic, it must be readable and accurate, so we can comment on what you actually built.  Looking at your schematic, my first comment would be that there is a short circuit across the speaker, and the bottom terminal of the WK resistor is not connected to anything.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that what you have is a voltage amplifier which is not capable of driving an 8\$\Omega\$ speaker. The output impedance is going to be right around what the collector resistor is, 1k. You are then trying to drive 8\$\Omega\$ with that. This is called an impedance mismatch.

So how much voltage can you get across the speaker? The 1k resistor and the speaker form a voltage divider, the maximum voltage across the speaker with a 9 V supply would be:
$$
V_{spk} = 9~V\times\frac{8\Omega}{1k + 8\Omega} = 71.4~mV
$$

That's not very much. At most you may get a few microwatts of power into the speaker. And that's not to mention that you need DC blocking capacitors on the input and output as mentioned in the comments.

This is what happens when you try to drive a low impedance load with a high impedance source, you get a lot of attenuation. It's basically like having a volume control turned almost all the way down.

Changing the resistor values as mentioned in the comments won't make much difference, the emitter resistor will have little affect on gain as it's already bypassed, and gain is not your problem anyway.

What you need is a whole new circuit. A push-pull amplifier pairing the 2N3904 NPN with a 2N3906 PNP is one option (as in the first link periblepsis commented). Your power would be limited as those are small signal transistors, not meant for much power, but with a 1/2 W speaker they may be enough. Otherwise you'd have to get some higher power transistors. Another option would be to go with something like an LM386 IC amplifier.

Years ago they may have used a similar circuit to this, but with an audio transformer in place of the collector resistor. This would match the transistor's impedance to the speaker impedance. This is rarely done today because of the cost and bulk of the transformer.